# Bash script that kill process when cpu is higher than x%

Tags: bash

I premise that i'm at the very first arms about this.

I'm trying to create a script that, when twice in a row, detects a % of cpu in use higher than 70%, it kills all the screens and python processes.

For how the script is currently, I do not get errors but I know that it does not work as it should.

Could someone help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
a=0
b=2
now=$(date +"%T")
echo [$now] Start

while :
do      ###i take this 3 line online to check the cpu usage %
    cores=$(nproc) 
    load=$(awk '{print $3}'< /proc/loadavg)
    usage=$(echo | awk -v c="${cores}" -v l="${load}" '{print l*100/c}' | awk -F. '{print $1}')
    if [[ ${usage} -ge 70 ]];
    then
        let "a += 1"
        if [[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]];
        then 
            echo
            echo ============================================
            echo
            now=$(date +"%T")
            echo -e "\e[33m[$now]\e[39m" CPU usage "\e[33m[$usage]\e[39m" 
            echo
            let "a=0"
            echo pkill screen  ###this 2 command is what i need to do
            echo pkill python  ###when the cpu is higher than 70%
            echo
            echo "processi chiusi"
            echo ============================================
            sleep 15
        else

            echo
            echo ============================================
            echo
            echo 
            echo
            now=$(date +"%T")
            echo -e "\e[33m[$now]\e[39m" CPU usage "\e[33m[$usage]\e[39m" 
            echo
            echo ============================================
            sleep 15
        fi

    else
        echo
        echo
        echo
        echo ============================================
        echo
        now=$(date +"%T")
        echo -e "\e[33m[$now]\e[39m" CPU usage "\e[33m[$usage]\e[39m" 
        let "a=0"
        echo
        echo "contatore: "
        echo "[$a]"
        echo ============================================
        sleep 15
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you count the number of cores inside the loop? Do you expect it to change while the script is running?

Comment: Why do you redirect `/proc/loadavg` into `awk`? `awk` expects a filename anyway, so `awk '...' /proc/loadavg` is all that's needed.

Comment: no haha sorry, my mistake, i fix it now

Comment: Why not do `now=$(date +"%T")` just once, instead of 3 times?

Comment: as I wrote in the comment above, because im at the beginning, not knowing how to detect the % of cpu in use, I copied that line online, I don't really know what it do, I know that it gives me the percentage

Comment: While your at it, the fewer lines of code to read, the easier it is to maintain. I would have one `sleep 15` at the bottom of the `while` loop and remove the ones inside the if/else if blocks. Using `pkill` is good, but it hides what it is doing, so you can't debug. (or is there a `-v` (verbose) option?). Assuming `pkill` is a shell script on your system, I could copy to a local dir in your PATH and add debugging output. (Or is that a compiled program?). Good luck.

Comment: i used it to know with understanding at what time it has detected the value

Comment: I would define a `bash` function called `update()` and call that from each of the 3 places rather than repeat all that code with `===` and escapes. Pass it the extra line that says `contatore` or `chiusi` as a parameter. https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php

Comment: OK, skip copying `pkill`. just the option `-e, --echo           #     display what is killed` so you know what it is doing. Good luck.

Comment: AND you want to think about what will happen when a different program besides `screen` and `python` are using more than 70%. It might be better for your program to send notifications about what it found, so someone can login and manually kill offending processes. Good luck.

Comment: i thinks its so hard for me, i dont understanding all, i thought that it was easier, anyway i delete all the sleeps and i replace one at the bottom, but, its normal that the "usage"variable dont return the same % that i see on htop?

Comment: however, to respond to @shellter , I'm trying to make this program as a temporary solution, I use a program that for now, while it performs his normal functions, for some unknown reason, creates continuously, numerous python processes that leads the server to overload (usually the CPU is 30%, when the program buggy, cpu reaches 100% and all lag.. waiting for a software update, I wanted to try to create this script to solve the problem temporarily, because I can not control constantly every second if everything is ok or not

Comment: Yes, not to get too distracted by all the imprefections, it is best to focus on your primary problem (Its not working) ;-) And to me, this means that `pkill` is not working the way you expect. Without the `-e` option, you have no way of knowing if it found a process to kill, or it just ran and quit without doing anything. That should help you significantly. But if see that `pkill` didn't try to kill anything (when it should have) then there is something about the processes, most likely that the user running the process is not you. (some more generic acct maybe). ....

Comment: ...  Fixing that will require more debugging info, usually generated with `ps ef| grep -E '[s]creen|[p]ython'`. If you need help debugging this, then best to post a new Q, just saying `pkill` has this output, `ps -ef...` has this output and the processes I want to die aren't being killed. AND output from "usage" will not match `htop` output. Don't worry about that. Good luck!!!